# Mongoid embeds_many documents are not removed after reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid3

I have the following two models:

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :locks, class_name: "Lock"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locks, allow_destroy: true

  field :name, type: String


  validates :name,
    presence: true

  belongs_to :list
end
```

and

```
class Lock
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :locked_by, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  embedded_in :customer, inverse_of: :locks, class_name: "Customer"

  def unlock!
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

So when I try to delete an lock the lock is removed from the child collection but **after reload** of customer it is **still there**:

```
locks = customer.locks.where({ some conditions})

locks.each do |l|
  l.unlock!
end

customer.save
```

The where conditions definitely returns the correct objects.

Can somebody help me and tell me what I did wrong?

**Update:**

This does not work also

```
customer.locks = []
customer.save
customer.reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets try.

First, delete this block

```
 def unlock!
    self.destroy
 end
```

Then, replace

```
locks = customer.locks.where({ some conditions})
locks.each do |l|
      l.unlock!
    end
```

with

```
 customer.locks.where({ some conditions}).delete_all
```

If still it does not work, please add this one more line after the line above

```
customer.locks.save
```